# Unknown action: The action could not be found for Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

This has been driving me nuts for a whole day.  I have the following in my ccpayment controller:

```
#"ccpayments.rb"

  def checkout
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('No invoice found with that invoice code')
  end
```

The raise error bit is for testing only... I removed the content to be sure I wasn't messing up something there.

Then in my routes I have

```
  scope "/:locale" do
    resources :jurisdictions, :except => ['show']
    resources :ccpayments do
      collection do
        get "checkout"
      end
    end
  end
```

A rake routes show

```
checkout_ccpayments GET  /:locale/ccpayments/checkout(.:format) ccpayments#checkout
```

However, when running this on ...:3000/en/ccpayments/checkout I get

> Unknown action The action 'checkout' could not be found for
>   CcpaymentsController

If I add a view it will show the view, but the action is never called.  I am sure I am missing something basic as I am a rails novice, but what?  Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said that your controller file is named `ccpayments.rb` but the standard naming system for controllers would make it `ccpayments_controller.rb`, so that would cause a action not found error. Try renaming your controller file and see if this fixes the problem.

Comment: The name of the controller class should also be `CcpaymentsController`.

Comment: Ok, here is the deal.  If you promise not to tell anyone I'll tell you a funny story: I have spent a whole day editing the model instead of the controller.  If you'll excuse me for minute I shall now go and jump out a window.